# Sendgrid email sending having issue with apostrophe ’ character?

Tags: java, email, encoding, sendgrid

I'm trying to send emails using SendGrid with Java. The apostrophe character appears like a ? (question mark).

I am sending the header to have text encoding as UTF-8 but it still appears like a question mark.

```
mailMessage.setHeaders("{'text':'UTF-8'}");
```

The above line has no effect. I am sure that the input HTML string I have is UTF-8 encoded. The email client is MS Outlook 2010

Answer (score 10):

I know this answer is 6.5 years too late for you but, as the issue is still happening for people and this post appears high up in google search,I thought I would offer an alternative solution.

On the template itself in SendGrid, you can simply escape these problematic characters by using a triple curly brace as opposed to a double. i.e.

> {{{recipient_name}}}

instead of

> {{recipient_name}}

This solution is hidden within the bowels of SendGrid documentation:

https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-nodejs/blob/master/packages/helpers/constants/index.js

Answer (score 7):

You have to pass your subject variable in triple curly braces ,so that it will parse as text instead of HTML 
you can pass it like this -  `{{{subject}}}`

or you can follow [all the steps](https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/index.html) again.

This one is worked for me.

Comment: This solution worked for me to have text variables working in the email subject with characters like '&'

Answer (score 2):

Setting the content-type in the header isn't actually the right way to change the content-type to UTF-8.  You need to actually set the type on the `BodyPart`.  For example:

```
// Create a message part to represent the body text 
BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart(); 
messageBodyPart.setContent( "<strong>some html content</strong>", "text/html; charset=utf-8" );
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you copy and paste the content from MS Word?

There are certain characters that don't render in html. You can manually replace all apostrophe characters by simply retyping it in your text editor, it will replace the MS Word slanted apostrophe with a standard vertical one, or if you like them to remain slanted, you can use `&ldquo;` or `&rdquo;`